# SQL Query to query 2 tables which has duplicate values

Tags: sql, mysql, database, hana, dbeaver

Example Tables:

Table: `TAB1`

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | AA1 | G1 |
| A1 | A2 | AA1 | G2 |

Table: `TAB2`

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | AA1 | H1 |
| A1 | A2 | AB1 | H2 |

How to write a query to get Expected Result as:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | AA1 | G1 | H1 |
| A1 | A2 | AB1 | G2 | H2 |

I tried join but i was getting duplicate values

How to write a query to get Expected Result as:

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | A2 | AA1 | G1 | H1 |
| A1 | A2 | AB1 | G2 | H2 |

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far

Comment: Where this `G4` comes from?

Comment: *"I tried join but i was getting duplicate values"* - how did you join? did you add `on` clause? also, the expected table and the one you get is very similar. anyway, this question need quite the edit to add detail - i could only help with formatting the table.

Comment: I guess the logic is join on row number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think you should use full Join

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM TAB1 UNION ALL SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 as Col5 FROM TAB2;
```

Please use this query.

Comment: This outputs 4 rows op is expecting 2.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood something.
I edited it.

Comment: Change `union all` to `union`

Comment: Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is called "equi-join".

The following code should work:

```
SELECT TAB1.Col1,TAB1.Col2,TAB1.Col3,TAB1.Col4,TAB2.Col4 FROM TAB1,TAB2 WHERE TAB1.Col3=TAB2.Col3;
```

Comment: `WHERE TAB1.Col1=TAB2.Col2` << it will give no row with sample from OP

Comment: My bad. I meant to write WHERE TAB1.Col3=TAB2.Col3

Comment: You should revisit and test. https://dbfiddle.uk/JkEfWrgz

Comment: Thank You for letting me know. I've made the necessary changes. https://dbfiddle.uk/cHTnSicW

Comment: Doesn't match desired outcome.

Comment: we wont get desired output

Comment: There is not condition and he/she want to get all table data from 2 tables.
I think so

Answer (score 0):

consider generating and joining on row number

```
DROP TABLE if exists t,t1;
create table t
(Col1 varchar(2), Col2 varchar(2),Col3 varchar(3), Col4  varchar(2));
insert into t values
('A1', 'A2', 'AA1', 'G1'),
('A1', 'A2', 'AA1', 'G2');

create table t1
(Col1 varchar(2), Col2 varchar(2),Col3 varchar(3), Col4  varchar(2));
insert into t1 values
('A1', 'A2', 'AA1', 'H1'),
('A1', 'A2', 'AB1', 'H2');

select a.col1,a.col2,b.col3,a.col4,b.col4 from
(
SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by col3,col4) rn FROM t
) a
join
(SELECT *,row_number() over (partition by col1,col2 order by col3,col4) rn FROM t1
)b on b.rn = a.rn;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/vaLEwV7A

Comment: Still not match wih expected result from OP. OP wants `G4 `

Comment: @User12345 Or is it a typo - voting to close as op is non responsive,,

Comment: This should work. Thanks